# ¿Como cargar un determinado script dependiendo del ancho de la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, responsive

Tengo un sitio web el cual esta adaptado para mobiles pero en ciertos puntos de interrupcion o break necesito que se ejecute cierto ´javascript´. Ejemplo:

Necesito que cuando la pantalla sea superior a 992 px se ejecute un evento ´Click´ y si es menor a esa resolucion que no se ejecute nada o solo envie una alerta que indique algo.

Lo que probé fue lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(Window).width() >= 992) {
            alert('Has cambiado el tamaño de la ventana');
            $(".sidenav-trigger").click(function () {
                alert("Handler for .click() called.");
                $("body").toggleClass("menuclose");
            });
        } else {
            alert("no entraste al if");
        }
    });
});
```

Pero por algún motivo no me funciona... ¿quien me puede ayudar en como poder hacer que se ejecute cierto script dependiendo de la pantalla del dispositivo?

Comment: Tienes algun error?

Comment: No ningún error, simplemente no funciona. Entra al ´if´ pero solo me ejecuta esta linea ´alert('Has cambiado el tamaño de la ventana');´ y el evento ´click´ nada. Si saco la linea del alert tampoco ejecuta el  evento click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que yo haría sería encapsular tu código en una función a parte la cual sería ejecutada inmediatamente cargue el documento, esto con el fin de no depender únicamente del evento `resize()` ya que al abrir tu sitio en un móvil éste evento obviamente no se va a ejecutar en primera instancia por que el usuario no está cambiando en ningún momento el tamaño de pantalla.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
         cambio();
    });
    
    cambio();
    
    function cambio(){
      if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
            alert('Has cambiado el tamaño de la ventana');
            $(".sidenav-trigger").click(function () {
                alert("Handler for .click() called.");
                $("body").toggleClass("menuclose");
            });
        } else {
            alert("no entraste al if");
            $(".sidenav-trigger").off();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="sidenav-trigger">Botón</button>
```

Comment: Le di click en el boton pero no entra al if ya que me deberia enviar este alert alert("Handler for .click() called.");

Comment: @vcasas extraño, en el snipet a pantalla completa (que obviamente es mayor a 992) funciona

Comment: Retiro lo dicho, ahora si funciono lo había ejecutado sin pantalla grande jaja. Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que solo declaras el handler, pero tienes que llamarlo explicitamente con `trigger` asi:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($(window).width() >= 992) {
            alert('Has cambiado el tamaño de la ventana');
            $(".sidenav-trigger").click(function () {
                alert("Handler for .click() called.");
                $("body").toggleClass("menuclose");
            });
            $(".sidenav-trigger").trigger('click');
        } else {
            alert("no entraste al if");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Solo entra al else... no entra al if

Comment: Talvez sea porque en tu codigo tienes `Window` con mayuscula.

Comment: No, copie tu mismo código que colocaste.

Comment: Yo tambien copie el codigo de tu pregunta pero ya edite mi respuesta.  Intenta copiar y pegar otra vez.